# How to recreate "default" .res file from command line?

Tags: delphi, build-automation, delphi-2009

When the "default" .res file of your project is missing Delphi will offer to recreate it when you open the project in the IDE. Can this functionality be invoked from command line?

Background:

A project is under version control, its .res file is *not* checked in (some musings about why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326172/delphi-res-files-and-git)). The project is checked out automatically and build from command line. The problem now is the missing .res file which causes the build to fail. Can I somehow invoke the auto-creation feature the IDE uses from command line? Otherwise it seems like I am forced to check in the .res file.

Comment: Either add the .res file to revision control, or build it yourself as a pre-build script

Comment: You mean building along dummzeuch's answer in the linked question? But I want it the easy way :-/

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht: yes, we also do not use the project's res file and use separate rc files for version and icon(s) that we build before the project is compiled. If you include the rc's in your dpr, building in the IDE does not require a pre-build step, the IDE will build them automatically. Any build server will still have to do it in a separate step though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try creating them by script. Just hoped for a less manual way.

Comment: This appears to be lossy as an application icon being copied directly to binary resource file.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no command-line tool in Delphi to re-create the default resource file.

That's just as well since you don't need the default resource file. It would contain a generic version number and a generic icon, which you obviously don't want in any project important enough for automated builds.

Binary resource files don't do well in source control, which is what prompted the other question. Write .rc files instead, and compile them as part of your build. Delphi won't auto-increment build numbers anymore, but it's easy enough to reproduce that in your build script as well by updating your .rc file (or generating an included file) prior to compilation.

If you really want a binary resource file, then you could store one in source control, but under a different name or location than what the compiler expects to find. After checkout but before the build, copy it into the proper location. Changes to the copy won't be recorded in source control.